# Error sending mail which worked previously

Tags: powershell, email

Below is the code snippet used to send mail. which worked until recently and is giving “Failure sending mail." Error. (Version: 5.1.16299.98)

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort =   "587"
$Username =   " "
$Password =   " "
$to =         " "
$cc =         "  " 
$subject =    "AUTOMATED "
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.To.Add($to)
$message.Cc.Add($cc)
$message.From = $username
$message.IsBodyHtml = $true 
$message.Body = 
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password);
$smtp.Send($message)
Write-Host "Mail Sent"
```

The error is:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At F:\powershell_scripts\xxx.ps1 :88 char:1
+ $smtp.Send($message)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on less secure apps in google settings  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps   and there is a typo in the network credential part `tial($Username, $Password);` (I am assuming this happened while pasting code to stackoverflow)

Comment: I have done all the necessary settings . this sometimes works when i put a debugger on the error line , wait and then run it . used to work properly before .

Comment: This `$smtp.EnableSSL = $true. tial($Username, $Password);` makes no sense. Something is missing. Is it a copy-paste error? Are you actually running it in ISE?

Comment: apologies for the error during code pasting , edited the code above

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you *what* the problem is, but I can help you to find out more information about your error!

```
try {
   <your code>
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $Error[0].Exception.StackTrace
    throw
}
```

`$Error` is a special variable in PowerShell that contains a list of the errors that have occurred. Check the documentation for more [/proper] explanation.

`$Error[0]` is the "most recent" error in the stack.

There are plenty of other properties of the `$Error` object that you may wish to interrogate for more verbose information... start with

```
$Error | Get-Member
```

and go from there.

Hope this helps you get to the bottom of this [and future] issue[s]!

Comment: gvee , tried ur suggestion , and i get ;                                       WARNING:    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(Interpret
edFrame frame)   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(I
nterpretedFrame frame)